# Google Script Map Function not returning value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cobbled together some code a while back and its been working well but now something has changed and it's no longer working as expected.   I have the line of code below which was working to return the location of the first time a matching value is found.   I am pretty green at this but the best I can tell is that the map function iterates through every element of the array and returns a value based on the function called.  In this case I believe the function is called e.

from the logs:
lookup_array (first 3 elements only) I also removed the data other than the first element of each array as that is the relevant data.

```
[

[AC, , , , ,]
, [AC, , , , , ]
, [AC, , , , , ]

...]
```

`newsheet_name = AC`

The desired output would be 0 in this case since the newsheet_name matches the first record in this array.  Unfortunately, I get a -1 result and can't figure out why.

```
var index = lookup_array.map(function(e) {return e[1]}).indexOf(newsheet_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

You need to return `e[0]` instead of `e[1]`. Remember, `JavaScript` indexes start from `0` and you want to get the first element in the array.

**Solution:**

```js
   const lookup_array = [
                        ["AC","","","",""],
                        ["AC","","","",""],
                        ["AC","","","",""],
                        ];
   const newsheet_name = "AC";
   const index =  lookup_array.map(e=>e[0]).indexOf(newsheet_name);
   console.log(index);
```

or if you don't want to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), then use your solution with `e[0]`:

```
const index = lookup_array.map(function(e) {return e[0]}).indexOf(newsheet_name);
```